# How to transform Gui jar into command line jar?

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line, jar, wrapper

I currently work on a big project. We use some code from a provider, and we want to include one of their jar in our software.

This jar is currently use for data restoration, and ask the backup file location through a GUI.

I checked with the provider, i can't use this jar in full command line.

I want to know if i can make a kind of wrapper which can fill and use this GUI without showing actually showing the GUI?

Comment: Can you call the same method(s) the GUI does?

Comment: Yes you can, but you don't want to do it. It will require some amount of really black magic and will bring you tons of pain each time you upgrade to new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand - this is not about **JAR** files. A JAR file is just a *container* for a java application. So the point is: that Java application raises an AWT/Swing/... UI to collect certain information and to then **drive** some "business logic".

Your only chance is: if that application is written in a reasonable way then it should have been written to *separate* the UI stuff from the actual business logic.

In other words: the UI is just asking for data; to then call some *other* classes. And those *other* classes have **no** relationship to UI things at all.

If that is true in your case, you can simply collect the required information yourself and push them into those "business logic" classes.

But if that provider did a *bad* job, then the GUI and the "business logic" parts are tightly coupled/entangled. In that case, there are only three choices:

- you give up
- you complain to your provider and ask them to **rework** their design, to come up with a solution that can be **driven** without *their* GUI application
- you try to reverse engineer what their GUI is actually doing; and then you try to build your own "driver" based on that

Depending on your context, efforts for option 3 can be anything between "impossible" and "easy to do". And even when you succeed in creating such a work around: now *your* code is tightly coupled to the delivery of that provider. Any change they make might break your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have try to decompile the jar and understand the "business logic". Their code seems pretty messy so it could take a long time, but it provide me a way to do this.

Comment: I know that risk. But this project will be use in a close environment and a offline system, with no update. This solution will be use temporarily. We already ask to our provider to produce a full command line jar, but we are a small compagny and our project is not their priority.

Answer (score 2):

Selenuim can do that sort of things.

You can also include it in a new project in eclipse and see if you can open the .class files (you might need a decompiler plugin), and if it is designed well enough and the GUI is decoupled from the logic you might be able to write a command line tool for it

Comment: Caveat: Selenium is intended for driving "web applications". So it very much depends on the actual type of GUI if Selenium can solve the problem. If the UI is a dumb, old AWT thing ... no chance.